# distinct Objective-C type Problem

Tags: objective-c, methods

I am having a problem. I have declared a method in my NetManager class with following signatures

```
-(void) getLiveMatchesListScreen:(AutumnViewController *)dataListener initialSleep:(long)initialSleep {
```

Where AutumnViewController is my custom UIViewController.

```
@interface AutumnViewController : UIViewController {
}
```

Now I am trying to call this getLiveMatchesListScreen: method from some other class by writing following code

```
[[NetManager getNetManager] getLiveMatchesListScreen:[[Resources getResources] getLiveMatchesView] initialSleep:0];
```

Where getLiveMatchesView in Resources class has following signatures and body

```
- (AutumnViewController*) getLiveMatchesView{
LiveMatchesViewController *liveController = [[LiveMatchesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LiveMatchesView" bundle:nil];
self.liveMatchesViewController = liveController;
[liveController release];
return self.liveMatchesViewController;
}
```

Where LiveMatchesViewController is a subclass of AutumnViewController.

```
@interface LiveMatchesViewController : AutumnViewController {
}
```

Now when i compile this code, i get following warning from xcode.

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'getLiveMatchesListScreen:initialSleep:' from distinct Objective-C types.

Can anyone please help me in this problem?
Thanks and Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the header declaration of getLiveMatchesView in Resources.h

What return value have you defined there?